# jQuery mouseover doesn't work with inline CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is: when a user hovers over the INCREASE link. The width of the red div should increase. Doesn't seem to want to work. Is it because of inline css?

Here is my code:

```
$("#increase_button").mouseover(function(){
    $("#bar").css("width", "50%");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 30%; height: 10px; border: 1px solid #AAA; margin-top: 12px; margin-right: 15px;">
    <div id="bar" style="width: 20%;background-color:red;height:100%; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="" id="increase_button"> INCREASE </a>
```

I even tried in css:

```
#increase_button:hover #bar{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6fe5/5/). How can I make the red div increase on hover?

Comment: Where is your `#popularity_bar`?

Comment: Your CSS will never match. `#bar` is NOT a child element of `#increase_button`, but your css is demanding it be that. Plus, CSS cannot be used to "reach across" the dom like that. It has a purely parent/child relationship, and can't do "nearby"-type matches, or even "change ancestor". You'll need to use Javascript for this.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you apply the solution to the code in your question? The severely reduces it's helpfulness and the question will likely be closed because the problem cannot be reproduced. Instead, please approve the solution you like and/or upvote helpful solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using pure CSS for a simple `hover` event like this. Make the `a` element a previous sibling in order to make use of the adjacent sibling combinator, `+` and then removed the inline styling on `#bar` - this was causing a conflicting specificity issue.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9v5aA/)

```
#bar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transition:all 2s;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
    -moz-transition:all 2s;
}
#increase_button:hover + div #bar {
    width: 50%;
}
```

If you insist on using jQuery:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5AHcj/)

```
$("#increase_button").mouseover(function(){
    $("#bar").css("width", "50%");
}).mouseleave(function () {     
    $("#bar").css("width", "20%");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your selector is wrong, your element has id `bar`.

Code:

```
$("#increase_button").mouseover(function(){
    $("#bar").css("width", "50%");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/J6fe5/4/